# How do we draw with java?

Tags: java, ascii, geometry

Ok so I've tried drawing a circle with ASCII for the past several hours. I have a predetermined set of X,Y,and Radius. But I don't know how to implement the centers (H,K). I managed to put the equations in java using Math.pow() and the equation I would like to use is (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = radius^2

Here is what I've done so far, and if i use the values h=11, k =4 I get a weird shape.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Well, what output do you get currently?

Comment: depending on my H,K I can either get a straight line, nothing, or an inverted "T" shape @SimonAndréForsberg

Comment: Please provide some ASCII output examples in your question.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg how do I do that on this website ?

Comment: What is the `a` variable in `Math.pow(posX-a,2)`

Comment: @omainegra OH sorry it was a typo.

Comment: this sounds like the interview question from hell

Comment: You click the "edit" button, add your ASCII output as a code-block to make all characters equal size.

Comment: Why did you remove all your code? That really didn't improve the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how is supposed to be your output, so this is my attempt.

```
public static void DrawMeACircle(int posX, int posY, int radius) {
    int h = 10; // Initial x position.
    int k = 5; 

    int x = posX - h;
    int y = posY - k;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2*posX; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= 2*posY; j++){
            double dx = (x - i);
            double dy = (y - j);

            if (Math.abs(dx*dx + dy*dy - radius*radius) < 5){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

With the values `posX=15, posY=15, radius=5, h=10 and k =5` it prints

```
    #####                  
   #     #                 
  #       #                
 #         #               
 #         #               
 #         #               
 #         #               
 #         #               
  #       #                
   #     #                 
    #####
```

Comment: @VescoPro change value of the threshold (now is 2) to 5 in  `if (Math.abs(dx*dx + dy*dy - radius*radius) < 2)` you can toy with this value to see if can archive what you want

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
public static void DrawMeACircle(int posX, int posY, int radius)   
{  
int thickness = 2;

  for (int j = 0; j<posY+radius*2 + thickness;j++)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i<posX+radius*2+thickness; i++)
    {
      if ( Math.abs(Math.pow(Math.pow(i-posX,2) + Math.pow(j-posY,2),.5) - radius*2) < thickness)
      {
        System.out.print("#"); // or X ?
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      //System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
  }
}
```

The result with x = 16, y = 11, radius = 5 and thickness = 2 looks a bit like this

```
        #########       
      #############     
     ###############    
    ######## ########   
   ######       ######  
  #####           ##### 
  ####             #### 
 #####             #####
 ####               ####
 ####               ####
 ####               ####
 ###                 ###
 ####               ####
 ####               ####
 ####               ####
 #####             #####
  ####             #### 
  #####           ##### 
   ######       ######  
    ######## ########   
     ###############    
      #############     
        #########
```

The fact that it is elongated is probably a matter of the font...

In order to provide a "single line" circle no matter the radius and position, i'd say the only way is to edit it afterwards like this:

```
public static void DrawMeACircle(int posX, int posY, int radius) {  
  String [] result = new String [posY+radius*2+1];
  for (int j = 0; j<posY+radius*2+1;j++)
  {
    result[j] = "";
    for (int i = 0; i<posX+radius*2+1; i++)
    {
      float pointDistance = dist(i, j, posX, posY);
      if (pointDistance < radius*2) 
        result[j] +="#"; // or X ?
      else
        result[j]+=" ";
    }
  }
  boolean wholeLine = true;
  for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
    boolean started = false;
    if (!wholeLine && j < result.length-1 && !result[j+1].contains("#")) 
      wholeLine = true;

    if (!wholeLine)
      for (int i = 0; i < result[j].length()-1; i++) {
        if (result[j].charAt(i) != '#') continue;
        if (!started) 
          started = true;
        else if (started && result[j].charAt(i+1) != '#') {
        }
        else 
          result[j] = result[j].substring(0, i) + " " + result[j].substring(i+1);
      }
    if(wholeLine && result[j].contains("#")) wholeLine = false;
    System.out.println(result[j]);
  }
}
static float dist(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
  return (int)Math.abs(Math.pow(Math.pow(x1-x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1-y2, 2), .5));
}
```

which will (no matter what you throw at it) result in something like this:

```
     #######     
   #         #   
  #           #  
  #           #  
 #             # 
 #             # 
 #             # 
 #             # 
 #             # 
 #             # 
 #             # 
  #           #  
  #           #  
   #         #   
     #######
```

Comment: That's something that I'm looking for but I don't want the tickness, how can I remove it ? I get an error in the if statement when I try. This is what I'm trying to reproduce http://imgur.com/56PSo3W